# Is there a Trello keyboard shortcut to add a checklist?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts

**Question**

[Trello](https://trello.com) has numerous [keyboard shortcuts](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/956705-using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-trello).

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the "Add checklist..." action on a card?

**Use case**

1. Create a new card: <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Select the card: <kbd>Arrow key</kbd>
3. Open the card: <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Add checklist to the card: `???`

In step 4, after opening the card,

- adding a label would be <kbd>L</kbd>,
- assigning a member would be <kbd>A</kbd>,
- but how to add a checklist with the keyboard?

**Research**

I haven't found any issues or open tasks for that on the Trello [development board](https://trello.com/#b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update- 11/8/19

The minus key "-" can now be used to create a checklist when you are in a card.

Answer (score 6):

You can now create checklists from within a card by using the <kbd>-</kbd> key. All keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](https://trello.com/shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

The Minus '-' sign adds a checklist to the card
[image]